# git does not merge the branches correctly

Tags: git, merge

I had a curious problem for me, when doing merge enters 2 branches

in the **one** branch the **a.py** file has 90 lines of code,
then the merge is made to the **two** branch and the same file **a.py** that comes from the **one** branch, now has 50 lines of code,

certain parts of the code do not appear, there are no problems of conflicts and no other *(if the p is compiled in the branch **two** fails because it needs the code that is not).*

Then changes are made to the **one** branch in the **a.py** file and the merge is done again,
the new changes if they are mixed but the previous ones do not

I have deleted the git cache, and I have even cloned the repository again, but it remains the same part of the commits of the branch **one** do not pass to the branch **two**, (the new ones),

> The question is, if there is a specific criterion on the merge. or a special merge cache that stores these changes and does not apply them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging does not imply that a file will always grow. It depends on the history of both branches since they diverged. If on their last common ancestor that file had the same content as in branch *one* then on your  ranch *two* you deleted some lines.... if you merge, the file would remain as in branch *two*, no growing is to be expected. Something similar would happen if you deleted lines on both branches (having started from a file that is 100 lines, for example. Branch one deletes ten lines.... branch two removes another set of some 40 lines, not the same lines. When merging you should end up with a file roughly 50 lines).